# Custom pasting into empty datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, clipboard, copy-paste, webix

When I'm trying to paste into the empty area within the webix datatable, nothing happens and `onPaste` event doesn't occur.

Basically, I want to add a new item through onPaste even when existing data items aren't selected. But whether it's possible?

Something like the 'insert' operation in a list, but in my use-case the datatable can be empty after init (in the following sample I've added an item to make clipboard work). Here it is:

http://webix.com/snippet/9ae6635b

```
webix.ui({
  id:'grid',
  view:'datatable',
  select:true,
  clipboard:'custom',
  editable:true,
  columns:[
    { id:'id' },
    { id:'name', fillspace:true, editor:"text" },
    { id:'details' }      
  ],
  data: [ 
    {  }
  ],
  on:{
    onPaste: function(text){        
      this.add({ id:webix.uid(), name:text })
    }
  }
});
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Hey, since you have included "select:true", hence, in order to implement your "Paste" you have to first select any row and then CTRL+V will paste the copied text. Although, the custom code written by you for Paste is correct.

Comment: it's not enough for the desired use-case. However, I've managed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that 'clipbuffer' has focus only when datatable has the selection. Most probably it is required for data editing, detecting position or whatever. Anyway, the 'clipbuffer' can be focused manually:

```
var clipEvent = webix.event($$("grid").getNode(), "click", function(){
      webix.clipbuffer.focus();
});
```

Sample: http://webix.com/snippet/aa441e70